# C helper program for Python package

Tags: python, c, distutils

I am writing a Python package that, in normal operation, needs to run a helper program that's written in C.  The helper program ships as part of the package, and it doesn't make sense to try to run it independently.

1. How do I persuade Distutils to compile, and install to an appropriate location, an independent C program rather than a C extension module?
2. How should the Python part of the code locate and start the helper program?

N.B. Porting the actual code (especially the C helper) to Windows would necessitate a >90% rewrite, so I only care about making installation work on Unix.

Comment: why don't you change the helper to a module?

Comment: @Daniel The helper program wants total control over a bunch of legacy process-global state, like the signal handlers.  The Python interpreter also wants total control over some of those things.  It could probably be made to work, but it would be enough of a headache that I think persuading distutils to link the helper as an independent executable will be *less* of a headache.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty interesting.  I've never done this, but I think you can use the [distutils compiler](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.ccompiler) directly.

I checked out github for some possible examples that might give you inspiration.  Check out [this one](https://github.com/achimnol/pykorea-cext-examples/blob/0e831ef1bac069a960845708c9225df4a8a6f865/chi2-cffi/setup.py)

The filter I used was `distutils ccompiler language:python filename:setup.py` in case you want to extend it/trim it down